# A regex to delete text

Tags: regex, go

I want to use a regex to specify what text should I keep.

My string is like this

```
foo/bar/GET/v1/fuzz
foo/PUT/fuzz
foo/bar/POST/v1/fuzz/bar
```

I want to replace it with this

```
hello/GET/v1/fuzz
hello/PUT/fuzz
hello/POST/v1/fuzz/bar
```

Right now I have a regex like this

```golang
re := regexp.MustCompile("GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|CONNECT|OPTIONS|TRACE/*")
newStr := re.ReplaceAllString(str, "")
```

But I get this result: `foo/bar//v1/fuzz`

How can I build a regex for my case? Basically is replace everything until the HTTP verb.

Comment: Maybe you can use `re := regexp.MustCompile("^.*?((?:^|/)[A-Z]+(?:/|$))")` and then `newStr := re.ReplaceAllString(str, "hello$1")`

Comment: Almost. I has to check that has a valid http verb too.

Comment: I put your list back and posted a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```golang
re := regexp.MustCompile("^.*?((?:^|/)(?:GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|CONNECT|OPTIONS|TRACE)(?:/|$))")
newStr := re.ReplaceAllString(str, "hello$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/huvMPz/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any text, as short as possible
- `((?:^|/)(?:GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|CONNECT|OPTIONS|TRACE)(?:/|$))` - Group 1 (`$1`):

  - `(?:^|/)` - start of string or `/`
  - `(?:GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE|CONNECT|OPTIONS|TRACE)` - one of the verbs
  - `(?:/|$)` - end of string or `/`.